# RHEL - keeping a specific kernel version, possible?

Tags: rhel, kernel, configuration, software-updates

I was looking to keep a specific kernel version on my machine.  To prevent it from being overridden or removed without having to grow or up the # of kernels the system keeps as my only solution as suggested by editing the "installonly_limit=" in /etc/yum.conf.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Rhel release you can use exclude= or excludepkgs=  in yum.conf or dnf.conf.  The packages can be glob'ed so the full name isn't required.   This will also cause other packages which require a higher version of the kernel to fail.  This is not totally failsafe as it can be overridden when using yum or dnf command with ----disableexcludes  option.